# Add systemd-inhibt lock while Spotify is playing song

Tags: sound, suspend, systemd

I would like to prevent my PC from going to sleep while Spotify is playing a song. If Spotify is open but does not play a song, the PC should go to sleep regularly.
So is it possible to add a lock using systemd-inhibt (or is there a better alternative) whenever Spotify starts a song and remove it when the song is stopped?

Comment: I was working on a suspend problem for a bit, I think I found that Ubuntu does not respect systemd-inhibit.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Hmm, that would be sad. Do you know how they handle it instead?

Answer (score 1):

Since spotify still doesn't emit the described behavior shared by most media players on linux, I investigated how other media players are handling this to find some possible solutions. Here is what I found out:

Inhibitions are declared by processes using `dbus`. That is, a call to the `dbus` with the appropriate interface, method name and arguments is made (I spare out the details). As far as I see, the method name is uniformly `Inhibit` for all the different interfaces. The interfaces depend on the specific software used on the system. Here are the ones I found:

- `org.freedesktop.login1.Manager` (employed by `systemd`, system-bus)
- `org.gnome.SessionManager` (employed by `gnome`, session-bus)
- `org.freedesktop.PowerManagement` (employed by `xfce4`, session-bus)

There may be more interfaces for the different desktop environments. Common arguments are an application identifier, the reason for and the type of the inhibition.

Be aware that `systemd-inhibit --list` only list the inhibitors registered via `org.freedesktop.login1.Manager`. To print the inhibitors for, e.g., `org.gnome.SessionManager`, you can query the `dbus` directly: `dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.GetInhibitors` (cmp. `dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.ListInhibitors`).

For graphical applications implemented with GTK (like `spotify-client`), there is the API call `gtk_applicating_inhibit` doing the call to the `dbus` for you. To notice, this call registers to the interface on the system-bus and on the session-bus, proxied by the desktop environment session process.

To finally answer the question: This behavior is supposed to be realized by the application itself. Therefore, I opened a feature request for spotify to use `gtk_applicating_inhibit` and `gtk_applicating_uninhibit` accordingly (see https://community.spotify.com/t5/Idea-Submissions/Desktop-Don-t-go-to-sleep-when-playing-audio/idi-p/5507190).